# Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: solidity

What do I want to do?
I need 6 candidates started, where these:

1. They started with the 6 pre-defined avatars that were left in the contract;
2. They started with their respective numbers pre-defined in the contract (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
3. They started with the counting of confirmed votes and empty voters' cards;

As soon as the voting begins, that is, each user with their wallet, makes a transaction (voting), only the values ​​of the number of confirmed votes and voting voters will be added, the candidate's number and avatar will always remain the same.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

// Solidity files have to start with this pragma.
// It will be used by the Solidity compiler to validate its version.
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

enum VotingOption {
    Confirmed,
    Abstention
}

struct Votes {
    uint256 total;
    uint256 totalPercentage;
}

struct Elector {
    address wallet;
    VotingOption votingOption;
}

struct Candidate {
    uint256 number;
    string avatar;
    Votes confirmedVotes;
    mapping(address => Elector) electorsWhoVoted;
}

contract ElectronicVotingMachine {
    Votes abstentionVotes = Votes({ total: 0, totalPercentage: 0 });
    Elector[] electors;
    Candidate[6] candidates;
    string[6] candidateAvatar = [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-1.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-2.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-3.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-4.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-5.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-6.png"
    ];

    function _createCandidates() private {
        for(uint256 index = 0; index <= candidates.length; index++) {
            candidates.push(Candidate({
                number: index + 1,
                avatar: candidateAvatar[index],
                confirmedVotes: Votes({ total: 0, totalPercentage: 0 })
            }));
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        _createCandidates();
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.
  --> contracts/Token.sol:44:20:
   |
44 |             candidates.push(Candidate({
   |                             ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not push struct that has mapping in array. For example you can put your mapping inside the contract and mark it public if you want to. Also method push not working with static arrays, so i changed array to dynamic and defined length as 6 in for() cycle.

```
 enum VotingOption {
    Confirmed,
    Abstention
}

struct Votes {
    uint256 total;
    uint256 totalPercentage;
}

struct Elector {
    address wallet;
    VotingOption votingOption;
    
}

struct Candidate {
    uint256 number;
    string avatar;
    Votes confirmedVotes;
}

contract ElectronicVotingMachine {

mapping (address => Elector) public electorsWhoVoted;

Votes abstentionVotes = Votes({ total: 0, totalPercentage: 0 });
Elector[] electors;
Candidate[] candidates;
string[] candidateAvatar = [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-1.png",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-2.png",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-3.png",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-4.png",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-5.png",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-6.png"
];

function _createCandidates() private {
    for(uint256 index = 0; index <= 6; index++) {
        candidates.push(Candidate({
            number: index + 1,
            avatar: candidateAvatar[index],
            confirmedVotes: Votes({ total: 0, totalPercentage: 0 })
        }));
    }
}

constructor() {
    _createCandidates();
}
```

}